# android Proguard "failed to create task or type proguard"

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I'm following this tutorial to make an obfuscating proguard for my project:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/proguard-android-and-licensing-server.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29

But when I want to execute "ant release" at the last part, it turns error like this:

```
-dex-obfuscate:
 [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource proguard/ant/task.properties. It    could not be found.
 [delete] Deleting: /home/drikvi/workspace/SuitAuto/obf/original.jar
  [jar] Building jar: /home/drikvi/workspace/SuitAuto/obf/original.jar

 BUILD FAILED
 /home/drikvi/workspace/SuitAuto/add-proguard-release.xml:35: Problem: failed   to            create    task or type proguard
 Cause: The name is undefined.
 Action: Check the spelling.
 Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
 Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

and also, where can I find the proguard installation directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Proguard is now integrated into the Android build system. If you get the latest SDK and compatible plugin you don't need a separate Proguard installation. I can only assume that the blog you refer to was written before this happened. If you read [Proguard](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html)  and follow the steps outlined, you should have no more trouble

Answer (score 0):

If you use a separate Proguard. Add to local.properties path to your proguard

```
proguard.dir=C:\\Eclipse\\proguard4.6\\lib
```